# Does anyone know how to put inputs into this perl script or just know how to use this script?

Tags: perl

I have never used Perl before, but i got the script to run on my windows terminal but all it prints is:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------
                         eBoxSize
                        version 1.1
       calculation of the box size for ligand docking

       report bugs and issues to wfeinstein@lsu.edu
                                 michal@brylinski.org
------------------------------------------------------------

eBoxSize.pl <ligand file in SDF, PDBQT or MOL2>
```

So maybe I just don't know how to read this script. But I figured maybe I just needed to put the name of the file in between the left angled bracket and the right angled but that did not work. Can anyone help?

This is the code.
https://github.com/michal-brylinski/eboxsize/blob/master/eBoxSize-1.1.pl

I want to use this script to calculate the parameters of the pocket of a ligand-protein complex.

Comment: By the way, the word you tried to use is "caret"

Answer (score 2):

The author used `<description>` to represent a placeholder. You are not meant to keep the angled brackets.

For example, you might use

```
eBoxSize.pl foo.sdf
```

Comment: Okay i figured that out just now. Thanks